# ExtJs inheritance behaviour

Tags: javascript, inheritance, extjs

Can someone please explain this behavior to me.
Lets declare a class:

```
Ext.define('baseClass',{
    a:null,
    ar:[],

    add:function(v) {
        this.ar.push(v);
    },
    sayAr:function() {
        console.log(this.ar);
    },

    setA:function(v) {
        this.a= v;
    },
    sayA:function() {
        console.log(this.a);
    }
});
```

Now I create two objects

```
var a = Ext.create('baseClass');
var b = Ext.create('baseClass');
```

Test the property

```
a.setA(1);
b.setA(2);

a.sayA();
b.sayA();
```

This outputs

```
1
2
```

Everything is OK, but

```
a.add(1);
b.add(2);

a.sayAr();
b.sayAr();
```

We get

```
[1,2]
[1,2]
```

This I don't understand. Why does it use separate "a" properties but one "ar" array for both objects.
"ar" is not declared as static!
I don't get it at all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you put something in the class declaration, it means it gets pushed onto the object prototype (read: it gets shared across all instances). It's not really a problem for strings/numbers/bools, but for objects and arrays you'll see this behaviour come in to effect.

If you want to have an array/object per instance, then you need to explicitly add it in the instance:

```
Ext.define('baseClass',{
    a:null,

    constructor: function(){
        this.ar = [];
    }

    add:function(v) {
        this.ar.push(v);
    },
    sayAr:function() {
        console.log(this.ar);
    },

    setA:function(v) {
        this.a= v;
    },
    sayA:function() {
        console.log(this.a);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, can you please clarify why it works different with strings/numbers/bools

Comment: It doesn't make any distinction, it's just that arrays/objects are "reference" types.

Comment: strings/numbers/bools are immutable data types. The only way to manipulate the value is to re-assign a new value to the relevant property, which in most cases will apply the new value as a member of the specific instance (`this.a = "mystring"`). The prototype (shared) will remain untouched.

Answer (score 3):

That's because of this bit here:

```
Ext.define('baseClass',{
   a:null,
   ar:[], <--------------------------- you're instantiating an array object!
```

To make it clearer, the above code is equivalent to:

```
Ext.define('baseClass',{
   a:null,
   ar:new Array(),
```

So both objects share the same array because the object constructor only copies the reference to the array not the full array object.

Not sure how Ext.js handles constructors/initializers but you need to create the array during object construction not when you declare it....

OK, Googling gave me this:

```
Ext.define('baseClass',{
    constructor: function () {
        this.ar = [];
    },
```

That should solve your problem.